# How to use the artifact located in local .m2 repository instead of looking in nexus?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin, mvn-repo

I have an artifact in the form of an WAR file which i want to store in my local .m2 repository. This WAR file is NOT yet present elsewhere i.e in any other URL repository like nexus etc.

C:\Users\user1.m2\repository\com\mycompany\prodcode\myapp\2.3.1423\myapp-2.3.1423-test.war

Now when i run my POM using mvn then i want the WAR artifact i copied above to be used AND DO NOT maven to go and search the repositories (like nexus etc).

How can i do the same?

I have made following POM file changes but they don't seem to work. Is there anything i need  to do so that artifact i copied is the one used by the Maven build system?

```
<build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <id>download-dependencies</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.mycompany.prodcode</groupId> 
                                <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
                                <version>2.3.1423</version>
                                <classifier>test</classifier>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <includes>**/*.*</includes>
                                <outputDirectory>${master.dir}/myapp</outputDirectory>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
```

Comment: May be the basics needs to be cleared. Maven by default , will pull the artifact from remote repository if not found in user's .m2 repository (which is also called local repository) , so if you placed the expected artifact and mentioned the same version in your POM file, it will not pull it from remote, but if the library requires other dependencies those will be pulled certainly for the first time ! I hope the order is clear , `Read pom -> search local repo -> search remote repo `

Comment: If you have already an Maven project which produces the WAR file ... this means to put that into your local repository `$HOME/.m2/repository` which can simply being achieved by using `mvn install` on the appropriate project... There is no supplental configuration needed nor useful... etc.